# Is a 2D Array an Array of Pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

If I have:

```
int A[10][20];
printf("%p",A[3]);
```

it will print the address of `A[3][0]`.

However, I'd like to know if this one dimensional array `A[3]` containing pointers really exists, or it is calculated in some way.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the question is about "array of pointers". That wasn't declared.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Technically, I think, with a 2D array declared like that, there is no ***actual*** array of `int` pointers; just a contiguous block of 10x20 integers.

Comment: Ah, yes that's right, no pointers in A, just a contiguous block of integers.

Comment: Here 'A' is just a double pointer. Two dimensional arrays are stored in row major or column major way. The 'A' points to the base address of the array. Calculating the address of a pair of index could be done if the dimensions of the array and the sizeof data type it stores is known.

Comment: It's actually a really good question, when considering the more subtle aspects of the underlying memory arrangements.

Comment: A[k] is just a pointer to the start of the kth row. The second index will tell the offset.

Comment: @Revolver Yes, but the point is (pardon the pun) that it is a pointer whose value has to be calculated - there is no actual array of pointers to look through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have defined `A` means that the compiler will allocate for it a ***contiguous*** block of memory large enough to hold `10` x `20` (200) integers; see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) (scroll down to "Multidimesional arrays"). As I'm sure you realize, if you were to do `printf("%p", A);` you would see the address of the beginning of that allocated block.

Now, when the compiler sees the expression `A[3]`, it will add what it calculates as the necessary amount of "integer sizes" to the base address (that of `A`, or `A[0][0]`); in this case, it will add "3" (the index specified) *multiplied by* the combined size of all the other dimensions (in this case, there's only one, which is 20).

So, in your case, there is no ***actual*** array of pointers; just a memory block that the compiler can interpret according to how you described any part(s) of it.

However, in a more versatile approach, one can actually define a 2D array in terms of an ***actual*** array of pointers, like so:

```
int **A;
A = malloc(10 * sizeof(int*));
for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) A[n] = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
```

In this case, using `printf("%p",A[3]);` would still be valid, but it would give a very different offset value from `printf("%p",A);` or `printf("%p",A[0]);`.

*It's also, perhaps, worth noting that, even though these two different declarations for `A` can both resolve an individual element through an expression like `A[i][j]` (but the compiler would evaluate the addresses differently), there is here scope for major confusion! When, for example, passing such an array to a function: if the function expects data allocated in the second form, and you give it an array defined in the first form (and vice versa), you're gonna get major undefined behaviour .*

Comment: Thank you, I knew that method, that's why I got confused. Perhaps I'm not smart enough to understand what you wrote, I mean, what does the compiler "understand"? If the compiler "thinks" that he should jump to the address 3*20*sizeof(int) (for A[3]) why does it print the address and not the value stored? Thank you so much, I apologize for the question

Comment: You can't pass a two-dimensional array to a function accepting `int**`, unless you do explicit cast, in which case you've aimed into your own foot.

Comment: @Ruslan - I think you're right. However, recently, on SO, I came across something like that: passing an `int a[n][m]` argument, which my compiler groaned at, so I changed it to `int*[]`, which caused the implosion.

Comment: Dunno, gcc doesn't accept it any way: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2cd75c036d14b89

Comment: @AlessandroF In answer to your comment: the compiler **cannot** print an `int` value, because you've only provided one `[]` index. Thus, it has to interpret that as a pointer - the value of which it can (and must) calculate as described.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way to calculate the position:

```
for A[i][j]
the position of the memory block will be

pos = A + i*(number_of_columns_in_each_row) + j

here A is the pointer to the first element of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, I'd like to know if this one dimensional array A containing pointers really exists, or it is calculated in some way.

The way you defined the array `A` :

```
int A[10][20];
```

does not contain any pointers as elements of the array. it contains only integer elements.

if you want to make an array of pointers, which should be assigned to int-variables is defined like that:

```
int *A[10][20];
```

You also can set a pointer to the start of the array, which means element `[0] [0]`
by using:

```
int *pointer;
int *A[10][20];

pointer = &A;
```

You also be able to set the pointer slightly forwards according to each element by increase the pointer.

```
pointer++;
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the OP's question. We all know the actual array contains integers (not pointers). The question is, what happens when one references a singly-indexed array value? Is there a list of pointers to each 'row' made?

Comment: But look again at the OP's question, which was about the 'pointer' nature/value of `A[3]` (which ***is*** a ***one-dimensional*** array).

Comment: @Adrian where is the relation to any pointer(s)? he did not defined a pointer at all nor get one as return.

Comment: The code `printf("%p",A[3]);` refers to a pointer (actually, a one-dimensional array of integers interpreted as a pointer). OP's question was whether or not such an array of pointers actually exits in this case.

Comment: @Adrian So you mean his question is about: if pointers are stored inside `A[3]` at the memory place of each according array element, which premise is that there are actual no int values stored at the according array elements?